# Filtering The Loop For Single Page and Blog Page

Tags: loop, filters

I want to start a div when loop starts in a single page ( also in the blog page ). And end that div when loop ends.

Obviously using any filter hook or action hook.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example (adjust to suit your needs):

```
add_action('loop_start', function() {
   if ( is_single() || is_home() )
       echo '<div>';
});

add_action('loop_end', function() {
   if ( is_single() || is_home() )
       echo '</div>';
});
```

You may need to adjust the conditional statements further if you wish to target archive pages and the like — learn more about the [**template hierarchy here**](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

To understand these hooks further you should inspect [`the_post()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/query.php#L3731) and [`have_posts()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/query.php#L3731) methods within the [`WP_Query`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/query.php#L836) class in `wp-includes/query.php`.

But for your immediate pleasure...

[`loop_start`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/query.php#L3743) hook:

```
/**
 * Fires once the loop is started.
 *
 * @since 2.0.0
 *
 * @param WP_Query &$this The WP_Query instance (passed by reference).
 */
do_action_ref_array( 'loop_start', array( &$this ) );
```

[`loop_end`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/query.php#L3770) hook:

```
/**
 * Fires once the loop has ended.
 *
 * @since 2.0.0
 *
 * @param WP_Query &$this The WP_Query instance (passed by reference).
 */
do_action_ref_array( 'loop_end', array( &$this ) );
```

Comment: Viva la WordPress!